# Puppetserver 1.1.3 cannot contact LDAP

Tags: ldap, puppet

I have a horribly out-of-date puppet installation that's using the Rack puppetmaster service. I'm attempting to bring it slightly more up-to-date, and my first step is moving to puppetserver instead.

I've created a duplicate of the old server (call it new-puppetserver) with a duplicate of puppetdb running on the db server. I installed puppetserver 1.1.3 because doc on how to update from Rack suggested upgrading to newest version of puppetserver 1.1. Service runs, certificates work. However when attempting to run a puppet agent against new-puppetserver with a machine that's configured to use it as master, I get an LDAP error:

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Problem fetching managers for  from LDAP: Could not connect to LDAP: Could not connect to LDAP: Can't contact LDAP server at /etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/modules/companyusers/manifests/managers.pp:29 on node mymachine.corp.mycompany.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

The "managers.pp" is a manifest relying on info gleaned from LDAP. The old puppetmaster used LDAP connection for e.g. user data. Tcpdump shows that new-puppetserver contacts the ldap server on the proper port when the agent is run.

However, slapd.log of the LDAP server records no connections or even errors. I've checked that the puppetserver seems to use /etc/puppet.conf for LDAP settings, since changing e.g. the port there results in changes to tcpdump.

My /etc/puppet.conf:

```
[main]
server = new-puppetserver.corp.mycompany.com
logdir = /var/log/puppet
vardir = /var/lib/puppet
ssldir = $vardir/ssl
rundir = /var/run/puppet
prerun_command = $confdir/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command = $confdir/etckeeper-commit-post

[agent]
environment = production
pluginsync = true

[master]
environmentpath = $confdir/environments

storeconfigs = true
storeconfigs_backend = puppetdb

reports = store,puppetdb

ldapserver = ldapserver.corp.mycompany.com
ldapbase = dc=mycompany,dc=com
ldapssl = true
ldapport = 636
ldapuser = cn=puppet,ou=Accounts,dc=mycompany,dc=com
ldappassword = mypassword
```

I have installed one additional gem, the jruby-ldap-patched gem. My gem list currently looks like this:

```
# puppetserver gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jar-dependencies (0.1.13)
jruby-ldap-patched (0.0.3)
jruby-openssl (0.9.7 java)
json (1.8.0 java)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.2)
```

Any idea where I should look to get the LDAP connection working in a similar way it worked on the Rack puppetmaster?

Comment: Okay, so: jruby-ldap-patched doesn't seem to do SSL. jruby-ldap-0.0.2 is not working either. I'm not using ```node_terminus = ldap``` as the node information itself is not in ldap.

Comment: Now using jruby-ldap-0.0.2 and disabling SSL for a test (olcSecurity: ssf=0) the LDAP connection actually works, but I get a new error: `Problem fetching managers for mymachine from LDAP: failed to coerce java.lang.String to [Ljava.lang.String; at /etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/modules/companyuserusers/manifests/managers.pp:29 on node mymachine.corp.mycompany.com`

Answer (score 1):

So, even though I still have issues, it's no longer the LDAP connection that's the problem. LDAP connection started working when I downloaded the the jruby-ldap-0.0.2 (also works with jruby-ldap-0.0.3) gemfile and installed it with `puppetserver gem install jruby-ldap-0.0.2 --local` and then made it possible to contact my ldap server insecurely. Not super happy with the last part but eh.